# Maven dependency with sub multi module

Tags: java, spring, maven

I have this architecture

```
    mmsb
    |----pom.xml (packaging : pom) -> declare modules API and Utils
    |----api
    |    |----pom.xml (packaging : pom) -> declare module api-slack / parent project
    |    |----api-slack
    |         |----pom.xml (packaging : pom) -> declare module api-slack-core / parent api
    |         |----api-slack-core
    |              |----pom.xml (packaging : jar) -> java code / parent api-slack
    |----utils
    |    |----pom.xml (packaging : jar) -> java code / parent project / has dependency from api-slack-core
    |
```

And it not works

With clean install from root Maven say :

```
    ~/dev/maven-multi-sub-projets ⌚ 11:03:48
    $ mvn clean install -DskipTests

    Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -javaagent:/usr/share/java/jayatanaag.jar
    [INFO] Scanning for projects...
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Reactor Build Order:
    [INFO]
    [INFO] mmsb
    [INFO] api
    [INFO] api-slack
    [INFO] api-slack-core
    [INFO] utils
    [INFO]
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Building mmsb 1.0-SNAPSHOT
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO]
    [INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.6.1:clean (default-clean) @ mmsb ---
    [INFO]
    [INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.5.2:install (default-install) @ mmsb ---
    [INFO] Installing /home/mario/dev/maven-multi-sub-projets/pom.xml to /opt/maven/m2repo/fr/app/mmsb/1.0-SNAPSHOT/mmsb-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
    [INFO]
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Building api 1.0-SNAPSHOT
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO]
    [INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.6.1:clean (default-clean) @ api ---
    [INFO]
    [INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.5.2:install (default-install) @ api ---
    [INFO] Installing /home/mario/dev/maven-multi-sub-projets/api/pom.xml to /opt/maven/m2repo/fr/app/api/1.0-SNAPSHOT/api-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
    [INFO]
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Building api-slack 1.0-SNAPSHOT
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO]
    [INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.6.1:clean (default-clean) @ api-slack ---
    [INFO]
    [INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.5.2:install (default-install) @ api-slack ---
    [INFO] Installing /home/mario/dev/maven-multi-sub-projets/api/api-slack/pom.xml to /opt/maven/m2repo/fr/app/api-slack/1.0-SNAPSHOT/api-slack-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
    [INFO]
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Building api-slack-core 1.0-SNAPSHOT
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO]
    [INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.6.1:clean (default-clean) @ api-slack-core ---
    [INFO] Deleting /home/mario/dev/maven-multi-sub-projets/api/api-slack/api-slack-core/target
    [INFO]
    [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ api-slack-core ---
    [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
    [INFO] Copying 0 resource
    [INFO] Copying 0 resource
    [INFO]
    [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ api-slack-core ---
    [INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
    [INFO] Compiling 2 source files to /home/mario/dev/maven-multi-sub-projets/api/api-slack/api-slack-core/target/classes
    [INFO]
    [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ api-slack-core ---
    [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
    [INFO] Copying 0 resource
    [INFO]
    [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ api-slack-core ---
    [INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
    [INFO]
    [INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test (default-test) @ api-slack-core ---
    [INFO] Tests are skipped.
    [INFO]
    [INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.6:jar (default-jar) @ api-slack-core ---
    [INFO] Building jar: /home/mario/dev/maven-multi-sub-projets/api/api-slack/api-slack-core/target/api-slack-core-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
    [INFO]
    [INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.4.2.RELEASE:repackage (default) @ api-slack-core ---
    [INFO]
    [INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.5.2:install (default-install) @ api-slack-core ---
    [INFO] Installing /home/mario/dev/maven-multi-sub-projets/api/api-slack/api-slack-core/target/api-slack-core-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar to /opt/maven/m2repo/fr/app/api-slack-core/1.0-SNAPSHOT/api-slack-core-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
    [INFO] Installing /home/mario/dev/maven-multi-sub-projets/api/api-slack/api-slack-core/pom.xml to /opt/maven/m2repo/fr/app/api-slack-core/1.0-SNAPSHOT/api-slack-core-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
    [INFO]
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Building utils 1.0-SNAPSHOT
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO]
    [INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.6.1:clean (default-clean) @ utils ---
    [INFO] Deleting /home/mario/dev/maven-multi-sub-projets/utils/target
    [INFO]
    [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ utils ---
    [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
    [INFO] Copying 0 resource
    [INFO] Copying 0 resource
    [INFO]
    [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ utils ---
    [INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
    [INFO] Compiling 1 source file to /home/mario/dev/maven-multi-sub-projets/utils/target/classes
    [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
    [ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :
    [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
    [ERROR] /home/mario/dev/maven-multi-sub-projets/utils/src/main/java/fr/app/utils/Application.java:[3,29] package fr.app.api.slack.core does not exist
    [ERROR] /home/mario/dev/maven-multi-sub-projets/utils/src/main/java/fr/app/utils/Application.java:[11,13] cannot find symbol
    symbol:   class SlackService
    location: class fr.app.utils.Application
    [INFO] 2 errors
    [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Reactor Summary:
    [INFO]
    [INFO] mmsb ............................................... SUCCESS [  0.213 s]
    [INFO] api ................................................ SUCCESS [  0.005 s]
    [INFO] api-slack .......................................... SUCCESS [  0.004 s]
    [INFO] api-slack-core ..................................... SUCCESS [  1.558 s]
    [INFO] utils .............................................. FAILURE [  0.113 s]
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time: 2.197 s
    [INFO] Finished at: 2016-12-15T11:03:52+01:00
    [INFO] Final Memory: 32M/317M
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project utils: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
    [ERROR] /home/mario/dev/maven-multi-sub-projets/utils/src/main/java/fr/app/utils/Application.java:[3,29] package fr.app.api.slack.core does not exist
    [ERROR] /home/mario/dev/maven-multi-sub-projets/utils/src/main/java/fr/app/utils/Application.java:[11,13] cannot find symbol
    [ERROR] symbol:   class SlackService
    [ERROR] location: class fr.app.utils.Application
    [ERROR] -> [Help 1]
    [ERROR]
    [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
    [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
    [ERROR]
    [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
    [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
    [ERROR]
    [ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
    [ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :utils
```

How to declare dependency of api-slack-core in utils ?

UPDATE

I upload code in this repository : https://github.com/mmaryo/mmsb

The problem is when I import fr.app.api.slack.core.SlackService inside fr.app.utils.Application

UPDATE 2

I found the problem, I removed :

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: Have you performed `mvn clean install` from the root module  ?

Comment: Yes it's clean install from root

Comment: OK. Can you  show the pom of Utils and Api-slack-core modules ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few things here -

At your **parent** pom level (`project`), why do you still have `parent` declared?

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

that too with

```
<packaging>pom</packaging>
```

and along with that why do you have

```
<module>api-slack</module>
<module>api-slack-core</module>
```

if they are supposed to be hierarchically within `api` -> `api-slack` -> `api-slack-core`. As an improvement please move `module` out within the `project` level as well.

---

Then at **`Api`** level, I doubt how even `Api` is building currently with incorrect parent name -

```
<parent>
    <groupId>fr.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>vishnou</artifactId> <!-- modified -->
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
```

---

**Api-slack** seems fine.

---

**Api-slack-core** can get rid of redundant empty

```
<dependencies></dependencies>
```

and specify a version for `plugin`(unless already defined in any of the parent poms) as -

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>x.y.z</version>
</plugin>
```

---

Further **Utils** can use `Api-slack-core` as a dependency and also please change

```
<groupId>fr.app</groupId>
<artifactId>utils</artifactId> <!--changed-->
```

---

Overall, I would suggest you to please go through a [multi module example](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnex-book/reference/multimodule.html) as suggested by the [guide](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html) as well.

Comment: vishnou is the name of the project, I correct it because I change the name for stackoverflow

Comment: spring-boot-starter-parent is the parent of my parent (vishnou) because I use spring boot https://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/

Comment: hi nullpointer, I upload code on github. Hope you can help me

Answer (score 0):

Try running `mvn clean install -pl Utils -am` ? where `Utils` is the name of the module in the parent-pom.

Maven Reactor should figure out the dependencies by itself - you just need to put the GAV (groupid, artifactid, version) of your dependencies.